# Why we need Access-Control-Allow-Credentials when there is Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: http, cors, fetch-api

From [the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-allow-credentials) (as to response headers):

> `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`
>
> Indicates whether the response can be shared when request’s
> credentials mode is "include".

I have some difficulty uderstanding this header's purpose as it seems that

If a potentially malicious script tries to make a so-called "simple" cross-origin request  with credentials, all the server needs to hide the response from its eyes is not to include the current origin to the whitelist of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

If the script tries to make a so-called "preflighted" cross-origin request with credentials, the server can either prohibit this action at all or hide the response from the script by not including the current origin to the whitelist of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header on the preflight or actual request respectively.

So, why is nevertheless this header considered useful and not redundant?

Comment: It would prevent someone from sending a allowed non-simple request, but send browser cookies as well. Perhaps a server wants to allow any client to make request, but not authenticated ones. I agree it's less useful for reading bodies, but more useful for non-safe methods.

Comment: Evert's comment gives the reason. To refine on it further: You may want to allow credentials for _some_ requested resources or for requests for _some_ known origins, while disallowing credentials for other resources or from other known origins ー based on your precise knowledge about the exact resources and the apps running at the requesting origins, and what you know about the users of those apps. So, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials gives you fine-grained control over exactly which cross-origin requests you want to allow credentials for, and which you don’t want/need to allow credentials for.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is an opt-in by design so that the unauthenticated  behavior is preserved by default for cross-origin requests that were already allowed pre-CORS ー such as requests for images, stylesheets, and scripts ー while then enabling you to opt in to authenticated cross-origin requests for things like API endpoints (that weren't allowed anyway prior to CORS). It generally makes no sense to allow credentials for image requests, while it does make sense to allow credentials for API endpoints ー and even to allow credentialed API requests for some origins but not some others

Comment: But in any case,  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials can anyway only correctly be used with known (trusted) origins ー because you can't use it in combination with the wildcard value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin ー so the scenario of a malicious script running at an untrusted origin isn't relevant.